# Is there a way to periodically change the circuit a power supply is connected to?

Tags: power-supply, power, relay

I am attempting to build a device that contains an Arduino, a motor driver, and some motors. I'm using an AC to DC converter to power the device with 5v. What I'm trying to do is I want the power supply to be connected to a battery charging circuit at night and then in the morning I want the power supply to be connected to the motor driver. The battery then supplies power to the Arduino. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Would a relay be able to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is I want the power supply to be connected to a battery charging circuit at night and then in the morning I want the power supply to be connected to the motor driver.

Yes. There's nothing particularly difficult about this. You just need a microcontroller, a way for it to keep track of whether it's day or night, and a switching device that it can control.

> Would a relay be able to do this?

Yes. You might prefer to use a latching relay rather than one that needs its coil constantly driven to maintain a certain state. Or you might prefer a non-latching relay, depending on your full system requirements.

Depending on the amount of current being switched, and the voltage, it might be cheaper to use some MOSFETs or a solid-state relay (SSR) instead of an electromechanical relay.

Comment: Okay, thank you! The max current would be around 2A and voltage would be 5v. Would a power MOSFET be adequate?

Comment: @BCool, yes you should be able to find a power MOSFET for that requirement.